# Which Command is faster among ls -R and tree?

Tags: directory, ls, cat, tree

I want to list all the files in all the directories and save them to a text file to keep a record for various reasons.

**WHAT I HAVE**

- The D Drive and E Drive both consist of over 500 GB of data and over 20000 directories (approximately).
- There are a lot of libraries,datasets (custom) and projects with a lot of folders in one folder (depth upto 50 folders in 1 folder to 4 levels).

**WHAT I'VE DONE**

- I have run some test cases to check which is faster on the same directory and i have even checked the time

**RESULTS**

- i got **tree** command faster for a folder with 20 folders consisting of text files
- but i got **ls -R** command faster for a similar folder with 30 folders
- but if the number of levels are more tree is performing better.

**SOLUTIONS**

- which is faster among these two?
- is there any faster command which can list the files faster that i can use?

so if someone could answer this then it would be great as i have a deadline to change my operating system so i want to go with the fastest command so as to not waste any extra time.

*Thank you*

Comment: You can easily time both with the `time` command. Use `man time` for more info.

Comment: @mikewhatever 

{Latitude-E5410:~/Documents/sparse/implementation/datasets$ time tree > tree.txt

{real 0m0.402s}
{user 0m0.071s}
{sys         0m0.029s}

}


{Latitude-E5410:~/Documents/sparse/implementation/datasets$ time ls -R > tree.txt

{real 0m0.035s}
{user 0m0.021s}
{sys        0m0.018s}
} ...but this again changes if depth changes and no of folders change so it's not a constant increment of performance it varies too much

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the [edit] button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

**The time is taken for printing:**

Yes, When you run `ls -lR` or `tree`, the delay is caused because it takes time to print the output on to your terminal.

That is, 
When I Run `time ls -lR /` the time taken is :

```
real    0m7.693s
user    0m2.217s
sys 0m3.177s
```

But instead of printing it on the terminal, if I redirect it to a file,

```
time ls -lR / >somefile
```

Then the time taken is :

```
real    0m2.857s
user    0m1.360s
sys 0m1.487s
```

The same applies for `tree` (not much difference in time)

NOTE: If you want to allocate more resource and run with higher priority, you can use the `nice` command with `-n` option along with your command.